# Error 1175, MySQL. How to update or delete rows specified without PK, with safe update mode enabled in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I understand that it can be solved by disabling safe update mode. But is it possible without disabling it?

Code that I'm working on:

```sql
DELETE FROM product
WHERE product_key IS NOT NULL
AND collection = "RR12";
```

Comment: product_key is my primary_key. Thing is that it is not giving me error after adding the primary_key but the rows which are need to be deleted are not getting deleted though select clause is detecting those rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
Without a primary key, you'll need to provide additional criteria to ensure you delete the appropriate record.
```

You can do this with the where clause, But in my opinion using primary key is the best method

Comment: Additional criteria like what?